# What is the best practice for aggregating data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, reporting

I have a source table that is way too huge and queries take way too long for it to be usable directly for on-demand reporting.

The charts we generate are time-based, usually the resolution is in months or days, so my first idea was to create a "Months" table and a "Days" table, and to filter / sum / count into these tables, essentially running all possible queries in advance.

The question is how. My first idea was to write a C# console app to load all data for a month, and then somehow filter it (DataSet? DataView?) and then aggregate it (load into List<>? LinqToSQL?) and then update the Month and Day tables.

Is there a better way to do this? I apologize in advance for the lack of code in this post. I am writing this for advice BEFORE I start coding.

Comment: A best practice would be summarization tables that can be used by users.  These could be created by triggers or by jobs that run periodically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what kind of "jobs"? Is there a specific technology you recommend?

Comment: Perhaps, also, however, the reason the queries are slow is because of (poor) index choices or non-SARGable clauses. SQL Server is (normally) pretty good at dealing with very large datasets at speed. It might be interesting, as well, to see one of the slow performing query's SQL

Comment: Write some INSERT statements that aggregates this data and every day/month insert your new data into summary tables so your server doesn't have to perform aggregation on every request. You can schedule jobs in [Sql Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017). I definitely wouldn't write a program to do this as this is pretty basic database level stuff (or shell script and cron job)

Comment: @Larnu - the following query takes 1:38 to run:

'SELECT
 SUM(AMT)
FROM
 Transactions
WHERE
 TIME_STAMP >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00' AND
 TIME_STAMP < '2017-11-12 00:00:00''

Comment: Do you have any indexes on `TIME_STAMP` and/or `AMT`? A simple query like that should not be taking almost 2 minutes to complete.

Comment: @Larnu I have a "Clustered ColumnStore Index" on the table. Nothing specific to those fields. I have no idea how / why to create indices. I am a C# coder with minimal SQL experience.

Comment: Could you obtain the DDL for the indexes and add them to your post? I almost, however, wonder if you might be better posting another question for help on the query speed.

Comment: @Larnu.. I don't even know what a DDL is.

Comment: Data Definition Language. So, we'd need the `CREATE` scripts for your table and relevant indexes.

Comment: @Larnu - you will find nothing interesting in them. Just basic create, a list of columns and data types, no primary key, no indicies. Then, create clustered columnstore index, no parameters. Nada.

Comment: I think we've found your problem then. You need to have some helpful indexes on your table. At the moment, when you run that query above, it'll need to scan **every** row. I don't know how many rows you have, but that's why it's taking so long. But, as an example, if you have say data for the last 10 years, and have 1,000 entries (on average) every day, that's 3.65M rows where it'll have to check the value of `TIME_STAMP`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174286/discussion-between-infin8loop-and-larnu).

Comment: This isn't something that can easily be discussed in chat. You'll be far better off making a new question, with your DDL, and explaining there so that others, including myself, can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents would be to create a calendar table( with some surrogate key) and use SSIS to aggregate the data.